# GetKeyState function returning a wrong value

Tags: c++, winapi, keyboard, keypress

After I press the directional arrow ON, why does the function `GetKeyState` continue to give me a value greater than 0?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
    {
        if(GetKeyState(VK_UP))
        {
            cout << "UP pressed" << endl;
        }
        else
            cout << "UP not pressed" << endl;
            
        Sleep(150);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/windows/desktop/ms646301.aspx):

> The key status returned from this function changes as a thread reads
>   key messages from its message queue. The status does not reflect the
>   interrupt-level state associated with the hardware. Use the
>   GetAsyncKeyState function to retrieve that information.

Since you are not processing messages, you'll want to call `GetAsyncKeyState` instead.

Test for the key being pressed like this:

```
if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_UP) < 0)
    // key is pressed
```

Answer (score 1):

GetKeyState doesn't return a "boolean-like".
Take a look at the documentation :

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301(v=vs.85).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

It seems that you need to do :

```
if (GetKeyState(VK_UP) & 0x8000)
{
  //Your code
}
else
{
  // Not pressed
}
```

0x8000 if the result is a short or -127/-128 if the result is a char. Check the "return value" section of the documentation to see what you want

Comment: That's not helpful. The core issue is explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24506248/1889329).

Answer (score 0):

and also, GetKeyState() function, can be used for normal character keys like 'a' ~ 'Z'. (it's not case sensitive)

```
    if (GetKeyState('A' & 0x8000)
    {
        // code for Pressed
    }
    else
    {
        // code for Not Pressed
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please make sure your answer responds directly to the question set by the OP.

Comment: I think your binary '&' operator is in the wrong place. Don't you mean if ( GetKeyState('A') & 0x8000) { } else { }