# GetKeyboardState can't detect while i am pressing the key

Tags: c++, winapi, keyboard

I am trying to understand how `GetKeyboardState()` works. I have read through the introduction to virtual keys in the [Keyboard Input Model](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/windows/desktop/ms646267(v=vs.85).aspx#_win32_Keyboard_Input_Model)
and the [`GetKeyboardState()` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms646299.aspx).

From my understanding, `GetKeyboardState()` should state all the key status in the array it returns. So I was trying to see if there is any difference in the following code when I toggle the <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key on and off:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    INPUT buffer[1];
    bool stop = false;
    unsigned char kbstate[256];
    int timer = 0;
    MouseSetup(buffer);
    char result = 0;
    //doesn't work right now
    do{

        timer++;
        Sleep(3000);
        std::cout << "function output: " << GetKeyboardState(kbstate) << std::endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            std::cout << (int)kbstate[i];
            if (i % 16 == 0){
                std::cout << std::endl;
            }
        }
        std::cout << std::endl;
    } while (!result);
    return 0;
}
```

My output from both cap and uncap are the same.

I guess the way I understand `GetKeyboardState()` is wrong. Can someone tell me where I am going wrong?

---

Never mind, I got it. Here is what I really want to do. Thanks a lot for all your help guys.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    INPUT buffer[1];
    bool stop = false;
    unsigned char ifPress[256];
    int timer = 0;
    char result = 0;
    std::cout << "press any key to quite" << std::endl;
    do{
        timer++;
        Sleep(100);
        //check all the status if any key is pressed
        for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
            ifPress[i] = GetAsyncKeyState(i);
        }
        //if any key is pressed, change the status to the result
        //and the loop will be quit
        for (int j = 1; j < 256; j++){
            result = result || ifPress[j];
        }
    } while (!result);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Turning caps lock on and off doesn't change which keys you pressed. The documentation you linked to explains how to determine whether Caps Lock is on. Did you read it?

Comment: But in the GetKeyboardState documentation they say:"If the high-order bit is 1, the key is down; otherwise, it is up. If the key is a toggle key, for example CAPS LOCK, then the low-order bit is 1 when the key is toggled and is 0 if the key is untoggled. The low-order bit is meaningless for non-toggle keys. A toggle key is said to be toggled when it is turned on. A toggle key's indicator light (if any) on the keyboard will be on when the key is toggled, and off when the key is untoggled."

Comment: Yes, that is the part that explains how to determine whether Caps Lock is on. What is the problem?

Comment: OK. So my problem is no matter i turn on or turn off cap lock, for example I am pressing the letter "a" on my keyboard, the array output from my program does not change at all. I mean the 0 or 1 array there. Which I think it should have changed 1 bit, isn't it?

Comment: Or it will probably be more general to ask, what indeed is the information that kbstate[256] hold after GetKeyboardState function have been run once

Comment: No, the toggle bit is on the Caps Lock entry, because that's the key that was toggled...

Comment: GetKeyboardState() returns the synchronous state of the keyboard, the one it had when the OS last processed an input event for your process.  Which ensures that stuff like modifier and dead keys have the correct state.  That will not work when you don't pump a message loop yourself, the state won't get updated at all.  Common issue with C++ programs, their runtime library doesn't know yet that teletypes and terminals are obsolete.  You then have to use GetAsyncKeyState().

Comment: I think you skipped over "The status changes as a thread removes keyboard messages from its message queue. The status does not change as keyboard messages are posted to the thread's message queue" in the documentation.

Comment: I see. That is probably the part I missed. I will look through it more carefully to try to understand its process.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GetKeyState function in console program?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24506004/getkeystate-function)

Comment: Based on what I learned from this question so far, you can do whatever you want using it in your console program. The GetKey State is kind of like to realize some function like when you are holding shift, the number keys you type will give you symbols. It only check the moment when this line of code is ruining, what is the state of the key.

Answer (score -5):

Try to learn from this code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <Windows.h>
int main()
{
    int temp;
    BYTE arr[256];
    while(1)
    {
        memset(arr,0,sizeof(256));
        GetKeyState ( 0 ) ;
        if(GetKeyboardState(arr))
        {    
             for(int i=0;i<256;i++)
            {
                temp=(int)arr[i];
                temp>>=7;
                std::cout<<temp;
            }
            std::cout<<std::endl;
            Sleep(5000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    INPUT buffer[1];
 bool stop = false;
 unsigned char ifPress[256];
 char result = 0;
 do{
  timer++;
  Sleep(100);
  //check all the status if any key is pressed
  for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
   ifPress[i] = GetAsyncKeyState(i);
  }
  //if any key is pressed, change the status to the result
  //and the loop will be quit
  for (int j = 1; j < 256; j++){
   result = result || ifPress[j];
  }
 } while (!result);
    return 0;
}

Comment: What could we learn from this code? Beyond the fact that it too uses the synchronous state in error.

Comment: Even though not elegant, this solution is actually the only one I discovered in order to make GetKeyboardState work correctly (it's the Windows API I needed to use for a project).
When I found this answer I thought: also this guy found this workaround to make GetKeyboardState work! Great, it means it is a determinist solution!